# How to find specific file when given md5 Hash

Tags: ubuntu

Our server has been flagged as being part of a botnet, and we've been given the md5 hash values of the supposedly bad files.

All the examples and suggestions I've read don't quite match what I need. All I'm looking for is how to find this specific file based on the md5 hash we've been given.

Do I need to generate an md5 hash for each file on the computer and then compare it, or is there some easier way to search for this? If not, how would I go about this?

Comment: Maybe you can reduce the search space if you can find some database online where the MD5 hash is mapped to a potential filename of the malware.

Comment: Otherwise yes, if you have nothing but the MD5 you will have to hash every single file and compare the hash values. Start with files/directories which are most likely to be infected.

Comment: That was a great idea looking up the md5 hash @Hanno Binder, unfortunately this doesn't seem to be listed anywhere. That's too bad I really wanted that to work lol

Comment: Too bad :) - However, you can probably skip hashing pure data files, like MySQL databases &c first. Then, in the first pass, you could also skip all files that were modified *after* the time you got the MD5 hash. If a file was changed in only a single bit after the hash was generated the hash will be different per se. Both these approaches are heuristic, however, so to be really safe, you would have to scan the whole system to avoid missing some cleverly disguised piece of exectuable code.

Comment: On a side note, I find it kind of weird for an institution to only provide a bare MD5 without further metadata. It used to be common many years ago to write a self-modifying program to avoid detection by malware scanners and the like. Those detection company people should be a little more helpful, IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `find`

```
find /var/www -type f -exec md5sum {} + | grep '^md5sum_given'
```

Replace `/var/www` with the directory you want to scan, you can also scan root with `/`,but this might be very time and resource heavy, depending on your system.

Comment: Thanks pennywise, I'm giving it a try. It's probably going to take a long time since we don't have any way to narrow it down, we're going to have to search everything. Hopefully this will find it for us